# Only get previous node of first occurrence

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got the following XML:

```
<table>
  <row>
    <column>a</column>
    <column>2</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>b</column>
    <column>1</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>c</column>
    <column>4</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>d</column>
    <column>3</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>e</column>
    <column>4</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>f</column>
    <column>4</column>
  </row>
</table>
```

As only result of my XSLT, I want the number in the column before the first occurrence of a column containing '4'. So my result need to be `1`. How do I do this?

The only way I can think of is an `xsl:for-each`, so my XSLT is the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//table/row/column[2][.='4']">
  <xsl:if test="count(../../preceding-sibling::node()) + 1 = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/column[2]"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My problem is; the result now is `1 3 4`, while I only need it to be `1`, and as far as I know I can't break out of the `xsl:for-each` when I found the first occurrence.

I tried to solve it like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//table/row/column[2][.='4']">
  <xsl:if test="count(../../preceding-sibling::node()) + 1 = 1 and $rowFound=false">
    <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/column[2]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rowFound">true</xsl:variable>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But XSLT doesn't recognize the variable, so I get an error. Tried to solve it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="rowFound">false</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="//table/row/column[2][.='4']">
  <xsl:if test="count(../../preceding-sibling::node()) + 1 = 1 and $rowFound=false">
    <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/column[2]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rowFound">true</xsl:variable>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I then found out you can not reassign to a variable in XSLT.

What would be the way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot break of an `xsl:for-each` construct in XSLT, for the reason it is not actually a loop but a mapping construct. The XSLT processor may actually process the nodes it selects in parallel, for example.

You don't actually need an `xsl:for-each` here at all. The expression you want in this case is this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/table/row[following-sibling::row[1]/column = '4'][1]" />
```